# Split image into pixels(columns)

Tags: python, image, loops, split, pixel

Is there any way to split an image into pixels with any programming language? (I was thinking maybe python?).
So I could iterate through it by columns maybe.

I hope it's not a stupid question... Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can easily iterate over an image pixel by pixel. But that tends to be slow in interpreted languages like Python, so it's better to use higher level functions that can operate on whole images (or regions within an image), when practical. Take a look at [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/), which can be installed using pip, if you don't have it already.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with usage of opencv libarary and python. If you will have some troubles with finding package you could get it from this link http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. You need the following functions:

```
image=cv2.imread(location_of_image)
```

This function automatically perform conversion from specific type to type of numpy array. This is two dimensional array of pixels. You could get first dimension(y) and second(x) by typing:

```
y=image.shape[0] #length in first dimension
x=image.shape[1] #length in second dimension
```

Now you can do what ever you want with this pixels. You can split them between multiple arrays and perform different operations:

```
for i in range(0,y):
   for j in range(0,x):
        image[i][j] #<---this is value of single pixel
```

Also you may want to convert your image to gray shades to simplify operations:

```
image=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Now single pixel not a tuple like with RGB but value in range 0-255 (shades of gray).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, is there any way to get the brightness of a pixel?

Comment: Higher values - higher brightness, you can loop through all image with two for loops and decrement each value by some constant, this is amazing series you may want to watch it it give me a lot of insights https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z78zbnLlPUA&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdttJXlLtAJxJetJcqmqlQq